# get id from url in same page

Tags: php, mysql, get, toggle

I am using the toggle visibility function in order to display and hide divs in one page.

Clicking on this link News makes a div visible where all the current news are displayed from the database using this code.

```
        <?php 
include"scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$news="";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `news` 
ORDER BY date DESC"); 
$newsCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($newsCount>0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id=$row["id"];
        $title=$row["title"];
        $text=$row["text"];
        $date=$row["date"];
        $news.=' <table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:150px;">' . $date . '</td>
    <td style="width:600px; overflow:hidden;"><a href="#?id=' . $id . '" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\');" style="color:#b19057;" >' . $title . '</a></td>
    <td style="width:50px"><a href="#?id=' . $id . '" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\');" style="color:#000;">...more</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
';
    }

}else {
    $news="No news available yet";
}

?>
```

The problem is that by clicking on the results, the div where the detailed news should appear, appears, but I can't get the data from the database.

I use this code the get the id sent from the previous links.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $newsid= preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$newsid' LIMIT 1");
    $newsCount1 = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
    if ($newsCount1 > 0) { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $dettitle = $row["title"];
        $dettext = $row["text"];
        $detdate = $row["date"];

    }


    }
    else {
        echo "No news with that id";
        exit();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of the value of `_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

How to get the variable with PHP?
Let's say you have a PHP page named people.php. Now you can call this page using the following URL:

```
people.php?name=Joe
```

With PHP, you will be able to get the value of the variable 'name' like this:

```
$_GET["name"]
```

So, you use documentation `$_GET` to find the value of a named variable. Let's try it in an example:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Query string</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    // The value of the variable name is found
    echo "<h1>Hello " . $_GET["name"] . "</h1>";

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its because you are using '#' in link

Change `href="#?id=' . $id . '"` to `href="?id=' . $id . '"`

If you are not refreshing the page then you should use ajax for this.

Comment: I think that, this might be the problem. Although I can see the ID in the url, I cant get it without refreshing the page

Comment: Then you should go for ajax. Send request to that particular page url using ajax, pass id and then get response(html) to add it to your div.